# Difference between instance variables and instances in java

Tags: java, object

I am just starting out with Java and I wanted to know what the difference between instance variables and instances was.

See code example below:

```
              class Dog {

                  int age;

                public Dog() {


                }

                    public static void main(String[] args) {

                    }
                }
```

Why is that 'Int age;' is underneath 'class dog' and not underneath 'public dog'

Thanks,

Comment: Who ever said that you can't declare a variable under the constructor?

Comment: What is the difference between declaring a variable under a constructor and declaring a variable under a class?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: If you declare a variable inside of a constructor, then it's a local variable.  Methods can have local variables too.  I'm not sure if that's what you mean by "under".

Comment: The order of variable/method/constructor declarations doesn't matter in normal cases except that it's a common practice to use a given code structure within a class; this keeps the code organized and more maintainable. Have a look at the [Google code conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.4-class-declaration) for more information.

Comment: You can read through the tutorial if you want to know more.  Most of this stuff is basic and easily learned with a little effort.  Here's one page of the tutorial, use the menus on the left to read other pages: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: @markspace to add onto that, this resource is also very effective and in my opinion has a better fit: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, variables meant to be accessible as attributes of objects of a certain class are declared in the body/block of the class definition.

Objects of a class are referred to as **instances** of that class.

Attributes defined on the class and holding data about specific objects are **instance variables** (not to be confused with class/static variables, which are also declared in the body of the class, but have a `static` modifier).

As far as variable declaration is concerned, constructors are like methods, meaning that "variables" declared in them are local-scoped.